# In PHP: How to store the current time/date in UTC format in a string?

Tags: php, datetime, utc

example:

$date = 'Wed, 18 Feb 2009 16:03:52 GMT';

//How can I get $date to equal the current time in the same format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean how to get similar format as that? As there is no exact match in the predefined date constants, this would do it:

```
$date = gmdate('D, j M Y H:i:s e');
```

That would return the current date and time in the same format as 'Wed, 18 Feb 2009 16:03:52 GMT'.

**EDIT**

GMT and UTC are (in normal cases) completely interchangeable, and as gmdate always returns an GMT/UTC date, you can just use this:

```
$date = gmdate('D, j M Y H:i:s').' GMT';
```

Or, as it turns out, you can replace e with T to get GMT:

```
$date = gmdate('D, j M Y H:i:s T');
```

Comment: Looks good but I'm trying to fill the value of a web header that is very specific about the format. The above function returns something like: 
Tue, 15 Dec 2009 20:59:04 UTC

Do you know why the UTC at the end instead of th GMT and if there is anything I can do to make it GMT instead?

Comment: my version is much shorter ;-)

Comment: @stormist: Just change the "e" to "T": $date = gmdate('D, j M Y H:i:s T');  "e" is the identifier ("UTC", "America/Chicago") and "T" is the abbreviation ("GMT", "CST").

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand, but if you merely want to convert the string, you can use `strtotime()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = gmdate(DATE_RFC822);
```

Comment: RFC 822 returnf for example: 'Mon, 15 Aug 05 15:52:01 +0000', not *exactly* what the OP wanted.

Comment: Tatu beat me to it, nice try though I did check it out

Answer (score 0):

Look at Carbon - PHP API extension for DateTime
(Link - https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon)

```
$now = Carbon::now('UTC');
```

You can access individual values as follows

```
$y = $now->year;
$h = $now->hour; // and so no
```

While you can use format() to get expected date format as follows

```
$str_date = $now->format('D, d M Y H:i:s T'); // "Mon, 27 Apr 2015 22:12:30 UTC"
```